# MySQL: delete a row ignoring foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

so I am working on a few tables and there are some data inconsistency between them... One or two tables have a foreign key constraint on a particular table (call it table X), but that table has multiple rows with the foreign key column.

What I want to do is to remove the duplicated rows in table X, but the foreign key constraint is preventing me from doing this. Is there a way to force delete the rows while ignoring the foreign key constraint since I know what I'm doing?

Comment: Be aware that you can mess up your DB while using SET foreign_key_checks = 0. Use it only if you know exactly what will be it outcome. I use it only for my php backup script.

Comment: Of course, doing so will be dangerous and I will use it only when I know exactly what I'm doing.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

`SET foreign_key_checks = 0;`

That will prevent MySQL from checking foreign keys. Make sure to set it back to 1 when you are done though.

Also, you could always drop the foreign key and then add it later if you wanted to only affect a singular key

`ALTER TABLE tableName DROP FOREIGN KEY fk;`

Comment: i guess you don't have to set foreign key check back to 1 if you're immediately logging out of the session.

Comment: i have multiple  table  so i want to delete this field from all table so how can i do this. this will not working

Comment: Bear in mind that this will leave orphaned rows, it doesn't force delete any child records.

Comment: You might want to run an [integrity check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5977191/3779853) afterwards

Comment: SET foreign_key_checks = 0; doesn't work for me. I still get `Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails` errors.

Answer (score 17):

Simply execute as follows:

1. Disable foreign key check

   SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
2. Delete your records

   DELETE FROM table_name WHERE {conditions};
3. Enable foreign key check

   SET foreign_key_checks = 1;

Credit: https://www.knowledgewalls.com/johnpeter/books/mysql/how-to-ignore-constraints-while-insertupdate-or-delete-records-in-mysql

Answer (score 2):

As some people already pointed out, ignoring a restricting foreign key leaves you with database inconsistencies. Preventing `DELETE`s is something you want in such cases.

You should better delete depending rows prior to the main query:

```
DELETE FROM cities WHERE country_id=3;
-- Afterwards you delete rows from the parent table without error:
DELETE FROM countries WHERE country_id=3;
```

Or, even better, change the foreign key once, so it does the deletion automatically (cascading):

```
ALTER TABLE cities DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk.cities.country_id`;
ALTER TABLE cities ADD CONSTRAINT `fk.cities.country_id` FOREIGN KEY (country_id)
    REFERENCES countries (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
-- From now on, just delete from the parent table:
DELETE FROM countries WHERE country_id=3;
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the accepted answer, you have to specify the constraint name after `DROP FOREIGN KEY`

You can check the constraint name by issuing `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

```
> SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name

Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tbl_name` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `foo_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `foo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`foo_id`)
)
```

In this case, "foo_ibfk_1" is the constraint name. So you can write:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName DROP FOREIGN KEY foo_ibfk_1;
```