# Laravel Eloquent's nullOnDelete always returns "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, mariadb

I can't roll back migrations because a foreign id constraint fails despite using `nullable()` for the respective `nullOnDelete()`/`onDelete('set null')` columns schema.

I have the following line in notes table schema:

```php
$table->foreignId('administrator_id')
    ->nullable()
    ->constrained()
    ->cascadeOnUpdate()
    ->onDelete('set null');
```

Migrations do run correctly, however, if I try to `migrate:refresh` it always fails with:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (Connection: mysql, SQL: drop table if exists `administrators`)

I've tried `nullOnDelete()` instead of `onDelete('set null')`, same issue.

The Laravel framework version is `10.10`, and the database I'm using is `MariaDB 11.0.2`.

Note that I don't want to cascade my entries on delete.

Comment: Have you tried disabling constraints during migrations? /E: And just seeing that you don't want to cascade on delete - which is fine - only the remark that this is what constraints are for. Double check for data that violate your current constraints, see Q&A: [Force InnoDB to recheck foreign keys on a table/tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2250775/367456).